# External keyboard shortcuts not working in atom or VS

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I have a laptop w/external keyboard and trying to use the shortcuts like CTRL +SHIFT + P and nothing works in either atom.io or VS with my external keyboard but the shortcuts work fine with the laptops keyboard. Is it a setting in the editor or my computer I need to look at?

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once and it was, believe it or not, the keyboards multipress  that was messing up. Did you test with another keyboard or is it just this one?

Comment: I have a spare in my basement it probably would be worth digging out and plugging in to eliminate if it's the keyboard it's self... I'm using the $39 reddragon s101 keyboard mouse combo from Amazon, might be a setting that's disabled my CTRL key or something stupid 

Comment: Got home and tried a few things... Goofy thing ever.... I got it to work using the right side CTRL +SHIFT... thought maybe a key was broke on the left side but I can do other things like copy and paste code ... But at least it's working .. for now

Comment: so faulty keyborad? or the backup behaved the same?

Comment: Actually its neither... It works fine with the right side CTRL SHIFT ... For some reason it won't accept that from my left side buttons...

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue with the exact same keyboard mouse combo (S101-BA-2 specifically that was written as the model on the keyboard), it turned out to be the `Left Ctrl + Shift` combo when pressed with any of: `[U,P,K,0,Backspace,F2,F6,F10,Print Screen]`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the external keyboard has a key, similar to Function Key on laptops. I had to switch its function, and shortcuts in VS started to work.